# Variable undefined when is it?

Tags: php, variables, undefined

Makes no sense to me why its not working, maybe im being stupid or blind but i cant work it out..

Notice: Undefined variable: info_table in file.php on line 35

Here is the code for it...

```
<?php 
require_once("includes/connect.php"); 
include("includes/functions.php"); 
?>
**<?php 
if (isset($_GET['info'])){
    $info_table = $_GET['info'];
} elseif (isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page_table = $_GET['page'];
}
?>**
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>

    <div id="content">
        <table id="table">
            <tr>
                <td id="nav">
                    <ul class="info">
                        <?php 
                            $result = get_all_info();
                            while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                echo "<li><a href=\"content.php?info=" . urlencode($info['id']) . "\">{$info["menu"]}</a></li>";
                            $result2 = get_pages_for_info($info['id']);
                                echo "<ul class=\"pages\">";
                            while ($page = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
                                echo "<li><a href=\"content.php?page=" . urlencode($page['id']) . "\">{$page["menu"]}</a></li>";
                            }
                                echo "</ul>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td id="main">
                    <h2>Main Content</h2>
                    **<?php echo $info_table; ?>**
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php 
    include("includes/footer.php"); 
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

can you help? lol!

Dont hate for me using tables, its an experimental and educational script im coding. Im not pro (yet!)

Many thanks!

Comment: The variable is only set if `isset($_GET['info']))` is true.

Comment: Ok thanks. How do i set it to true? lol

Comment: You're only setting the variable if the URL contains an `info` parameter (ie `page.php?info=something`). If that's not the case, it's not defined. The easiest way to solve an undefined variable error is to define it - just add `$info_table='';` after your include line

Comment: excellent, thanks! guess i was being dumb!

Comment: Not really - everyone here had to learn this sort of thing at some point :)

Comment: Yeah, thats why i love it here lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define $infotable as empty string outside the if condition

```
$info_table = "";
if (isset($_GET['info'])){
  $info_table = $_GET['info'];
}else...
```

so that , even if the condition is false $infotable is defined (however this prints empty string in `<td id="main">` if get info in not set)